# How to read invariant csv files using c#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, csv

I am working on Windows Application development using c#. I want to read a csv file from a directory and imported into sql server database table. I am successfully read and import the csv file data into database table if the file content is uniform. But I am unable to insert the file data with invariant form ex.Actually my csv file delimiter is tab('\t') and after getting individual fields I have a field that contains data like dcc

```
Name
----
xxx
xxx yyy
xx yy zz
```

and i rerieved data like xxx,yyy and xx,yy,zz so the insertion becomes problem.
How could i insert the data uniformly into a database table.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that your parser is reading the space between `xxx` and `yyy` as a delimiter, so it's trying to put it in the next field over? Is that space actually a tab?

Comment: yes sir exactly. that's why it split the single field into multiple pieces.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty easy.

Just read file line-by-line. Example on MSDN here:

[How to: Read Text from a File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db5x7c0d.aspx)

For each line use String.Split Method with your tab as delimiter. Method documentation and sample are here:

[String.Split Method (Char[], StringSplitOptions)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448.aspx)

Then working insert your data.

Answer (score 0):

If a CSV (or TSV) value contains a delimiter inside of it, then it should be surrounded by quotes. See the spec for more details: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180#page-3

So your input file is incorrectly formatted. If you can convince the input provider to fix this issue, that will be the best way to fix the problem. If not, other solutions may include:

- visually inspecting and editing the file to fix errors, or
- writing your parser program to have enough knowledge of your data expectations that it can correctly "guess" where the real delimiters are.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, the problem is that your code is splitting on spaces instead of on tabs.  Given you have read in the lines from the file, all you need to do is:

```
string[] fileLines;//from the file
foreach(string line in fileLines)
{
    string[] lineParts=line.Split(new char[]{'\t'});
}
```

and then do whatever you want with each `lineParts`.  The `\t` is the tab character.

If you're also asking about writing the lines to a database file...you can just read in tab-delimited files with the [Import Export Wizard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx) (assuming you're using Sql Server Mgmt Studio, but I'm sure there are comparable ways to import using other db management software).